# Auto-Delete spaces in VSC

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, spaces

I'm new in VSC and I have a simple problem, but I can't fix :(
When I write my code, everything it's okay, I use a simple tab to space some words...

```
  factory ReqRespRespuesta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  ReqRespRespuesta(
    page      : json['page'],
    perPage   : json['per_page'],
    total     : json['total'],
    totalPages: json['total_pages'],
    data     : List<Datum>.from(json['data'].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    support  :  Support.fromJson(json['support']),
  );
```

But when, I save the changes, the VSC edit my code and delete the spaces.

```
  factory ReqRespRespuesta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  ReqRespRespuesta(
    page: json['page'],
    perPage: json['per_page'],
    total: json['total'],
    totalPages: json['total_pages'],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json['data'].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    support: Support.fromJson(json['support']),
  );
```

How do I change this?

Comment: open the settings via File ->Preferences ->Settings and search "Format On Save",change it to "off"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your settings JSON file:

```json
"[dart]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
}
```